# How to avoid text overlaps in vertical tree diagrams?

Tags: d3.js, text, tree, nodes

I'm currently trying to convert a hierarchy from horizontal into vertical. I'm now facing the problem that when I have a lot of data and the nodes are pretty much packed together, their text will overlap making it unreadable.
Is it possible to somehow avoid this behavior?
Does the collision detection also work here maybe

[image: Overlapping text]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the nodeSize?

https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Tree-Layout.md#nodeSize

Comment: While this link may answer the question, link only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, you can improve this answer by taking vital parts of the link and putting it into your answer, this makes sure your answer is still an answer if the link gets changed or removed :)